# Installating VS2008 SP1 - bug

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I've been trying to install SP1 VS2008 and I get this error:

```
vs90sp1\VC_IA64Runtime.exe - Exe installer's log file/hint (%temp%\dd_VC_IA64Runtime*.txt|%temp%\..\dd_VC_IA64Runtime*.txt) does not exist or is invalid.
```

OS Vista 32-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=362464)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you're not still having this issue but I just had the same problem and was able to resolve it by uninstalling the Remote Debugger and then installing SP1. At first I couldn't uninstall SP1 and I needed to disable all my read-only drives first (e.g. virtual CD drives, physical CD drives and empty memory stick drive) before I could do that (no idea why). From there I was able to install SP1 though I also needed to install the SP1 ATL Security Update to get VS into a working state.